# How to combine fields with overlapping dates into one field

Tags: sql, postgresql, qlikview, overlapping, qliksense

Since I am new to Qlik Sense, I am not sure, but as I understood it does not work regular functions and some methods as in postgresql.

That's why this question, maybe someone has encountered this.
Is it possible in Qlik Sense to combine (compact) many fields with overlapping dates into one field?

Let me explain with an example, let's say I have the following fields: id_client, id_question, date_open, date_close.

The table looks like this, taking the id of one client:

| id_client | id_question | date_open | date_close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YZIYR00R | 14534534 | 11.01.2022 | 11.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 14786543 | 11.01.2022 | 11.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 87634957 | 11.01.2022 | 11.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 12398750 | 11.01.2022 | 12.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 36485023 | 13.01.2022 | 13.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 09748361 | 13.01.2022 | 14.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 56419453 | 13.01.2022 | 13.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 64324123 | 13.01.2022 | 15.01.2022 |

The logic is, if the dates of the questions overlap, they should connect and count as one question, but it is considered the next question and does not compact. Tried doing a window function, and then comparing that if the next date_open <= the date close in the first field, then the dates overlap and output date_close of the second line, but then stalemate and stupor.

The output should be

| id_client | id_question | date_open | date_close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YZIYR00R | 14534534 | 11.01.2022 | 12.01.2022 |
| YZIYR00R | 36485023 | 13.01.2022 | 15.01.2022 |

I'd be very grateful for your help

Comment: Just to be clear on the logic. Given a question (14534534 for example) find the last row with the same `date_open` as the top row and pick the last row `date_close`?

Comment: Stefan Stoichev, Not necessarily with the same opening date, as long as the dates are in the same range and overlap.

My task is as follows, I have a client who calls the operator with an appeal, and I would like, if the dates of his questions overlap, to combine them into one appeal.
That is, I go sequentially through the dates and compare the closing date and each following opening date, did I explain clearly?

Comment: @StefanStoichev

Answer (score 0):

If my assumption in the comment is correct then the script below can be used.

The idea of the script is:

- add `Index` to the original data. This is just an incremental id
- find the `min` and `max` values of the `Index` based on `date_open` and `id_question`
- once min and max are known then join back to the original table. This is just to "flag" the records that are of interest

- in a separate table (`TempRawData`)

  - load only records that have `minId` or `maxId` populated
  - create new column `id_question_repeat` that will have the `id_question` repeated. If the `minId` is changed then the `id_question` will change as well
    [image: temp table]
- the final table will use `TempRawData` and will group by the data by `id_client` and `id_question_repeat` to get min(date_open)`and`max(date_close)`
- Drop all other tables

The result table will be:

[image: Result]

P.S. Not sure how performant this solution will be in larger datasets

```
RawData:
LOAD 
  id_client, 
  id_question, 
  date#(date_open, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as date_open,
  date#(date_close, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as date_close,
  RowNo() as Index
;
Load * inline [
id_client,  id_question,    date_open ,     date_close
YZIYR00R ,  14534534   ,    11.01.2022,     11.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  14786543   ,    11.01.2022,     11.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  87634957   ,    11.01.2022,     11.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  12398750   ,    11.01.2022,     12.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  36485023   ,    13.01.2022,     13.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  09748361   ,    13.01.2022,     14.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  56419453   ,    13.01.2022,     13.01.2022
YZIYR00R ,  64324123   ,    13.01.2022,     15.01.2022
];

MinMax:
Load 
    min(Index) as minId,
    max(Index) as maxId
Resident
  RawData
Group By
  id_client,
  date_open
;

join (RawData)

Load
  minId,
  minId as Index
Resident
  MinMax
;

join (RawData)

Load
  maxId,
  maxId as Index
Resident
  MinMax
;

Drop Table MinMax;

NoConcatenate

TempRawData:
Load
  id_client,
  id_question,
  date_open,
  date_close,
  if(minId, id_question, peek('id_question')) as id_question_repeat
Resident
  RawData
Where
  minId > 0 or maxId > 0  
;

Temp1:
Load
  id_client,
  id_question_repeat                    as id_question,
  date(min(date_open), 'DD.MM.YYYY')    as date_open_real,
  date(max(date_close), 'DD.MM.YYYY')   as date_close_real
Resident
  TempRawData  
Group By
  id_client,
  id_question_repeat
;

Drop Table RawData;
Drop Table TempRawData;
```

Comment: Stefan Stoichev, if we add an inconsistent date to the table, will it also be collapsed? i.e. let's add row 9 where the dates (date_open - 11.01 and date_close - 12.01), will this column collapse or not collapse?